# Deploying war file together with resources

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have war file which I have deployed but after deploying the resources and links are not working.

```
<build>
    <finalName>KFA</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

> When I build the application I get kfa.war which i deploy to tomcat
>   but unfortunately I can't access any page, I get http status 404 -
>   /kfa/trainee. sample controller

```
 @Controller
@RequestMapping("/kfa/trainee")
 public class TraineeController {

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
TraineeService traineeService;
RegService regService;

@Autowired
public void setTraineeService(TraineeService traineeService) {
    this.traineeService = traineeService;
}

@Autowired
public void setRegService(RegService regService) {
    this.regService = regService;
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addMember(ModelMap model){
    model.addAttribute("module", "kfa/trainee");
    model.addAttribute("submodule", "add_trainee");
    model.addAttribute("title", "Trainee");
    model.addAttribute("subtitle", "Add");
    model.addAttribute("trainee", new Trainee());

    return new ModelAndView("/kfa/index", model);
  }
}
```

When I ran and deploy within intellij idea I get everything working fine. My question is how should i configure the build pasted above to allow me ran the war file on tomcat in another machine.

If not understood you can ask for more information. I will be glad for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deploy a war file called kfa.war in a tomcat container, tomcat assumes the context path /kfa if you don't give any other information while deploying.

Try to access /kfa/kfa/trainee.

But looking at the log files of your tomcat should help! You can install tomcat's manager war (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html) to get information about the installed WARs in your container going to /manager/html.

Comment: What if i don't want the duplication of /kfa/kfa/trainee?

Comment: Just remove the /kfa from the @RequestMapping. I don't know how you launch your webapp in IntelliJ. If you run it with a maven goal (jetty/tomcat) you can configure the context path in your pom.xml.

Comment: would you please provide the pom configuration? This my first application to deploy... I am running it with tomcat

Comment: Have a look at the section called "Using a different context path" here: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Great, @Denis. Maybe you could mark the answer as useful answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if your war has all the content that it is supposed to have by unzipping it.

If it does not have the required content make sure your project is using the right maven directory structure as mentioned here https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html.

If not you might have to restructure your project accordingly and everything should work as expected

Comment: 'src
+++main
+++++++java
+++++++webapp
++++++++++++++resources
++++++++++++++WEB-INF
' Within resources thats where i have my css, images, and js

Comment: Your structure looks right. As Paul has suggested it seems to be the way you are accessing it. You might have to remove /kfa from your mapping and returned model to make it work with /kfa/trainee url

Comment: if i remove /kfa from my controller within intellij idea the application is launched with {host}:{port}/trainee, when i take the generated war file and deploy on tomcat window the access now is at {host}:{port}/kfa/trainee and gets back to the error. The kfa added is due to the folder of extraction. how can i configure such that the folder is created but not taken into account?

Comment: In your tomcats conf/server.xml you can add <Context path="/" docBase="/kfa" />

Comment: I have tried it but no difference. Kindly please if you can write a sample app using intellij idea that i can follow i will appreciate. Thanks for the help @Johson Abraham